# What's the time-complexity function [ T(n) ] for these loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
j = n;
while (j>=1) {
    i = j; 
    while (i <= n) { cout<<"Printed"; i*= 2; }
    j /= 2; 
}
```

My goal is finding T(n) (function that gives us number of algorithm execution) whose order is expected to be n.log(n) but I need exact function which can work fine at least for n=1 to n=10 data

I have tried to predict the function, finally I ended in ******T(n) = floor((n-1)*log(n)) + n******

which is correct just for n=1 and n=2.

I should mention that I found that inaccurate function by converting the original code to the for-loop just like below :

```
for ( j = 1 ; j <= n ; j*= 2) {
    for ( i = j ; i<= n ;  i*=2 ) {
        cout << "Printed";
    }
}
```

Finally I appreciate your help to find the exact T(n) in advance.

Comment: I edited your post to be more readable. I want to know: what would be the type of `i` and `j` in your first and second example?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot , it is not mentioned in the problem so consider it  short integer and 10 Q 4 edition

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot  and also both algorithms do the same stuff, just different in syntax so I can use the log rep formula

Comment: The inner loop executes log(j) times. The outer loops executes log(n) times. Since j ≤ n, it is safe to conclude that T(n) = O((log n)²), although proving that T(n) = Θ((log n)²) might require a bit more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `log(x)` is the floor of log based 2

1.)
The inner loop is executed `1+log(N)-log(j)` the outer loop executed times `1+log(N)` with j=1,2,4...N times the overall complexity is `T(N)=log(N)log(N)+2*log(N)+1-(log(1)+log(2)+log(4)...+log(N))=  log(N)^2-(0+1+2+...+log(N))+2*log(N)+1= log(N)^2-log(N)(log(N)-1)/2+1= log(N)^2/2+3*log(N)/2+1`

2.) same here just in reverse order.

I know it is no proof but maybe easier to follow then math : [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MY6broExq) play with n. it always returns 0;

Comment: ln (x) is log of x in the base of e(Neper number) number that we call natural logarithm.

Do you mean log(x) in base of 2  by using ln(x)  ?

Comment: Normally I would not care about the base used for the log, since all logs differ by a multiplicative constant anyway. However, I recommend using `log` rather than `ln`. `ln` has always meant "natural logarithm", i.e., logarithm in base e.

Comment: well i didnt read the first line, got it thx

Comment: @Stef  thats true since we consider log(n) = logarithm of (n) in base 2 in computer science

Comment: I Edited it so now it is correct. I misscalculated first I also rewrote using `log` not `ln`

Comment: the outer loop repeats in (log(n) +1 ) times,

Comment: also better to mention that the variable j ends in N only if  n is in the form of pow(2,n)

Comment: @SanaAllahKheiri I edited it so now it is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Outer loop and inner loop are both  `O(log₂ N)`.

So total time is

`O(log₁₀ N * log₂ N)` == `O(2 * log₂ N)`

Which just gets reduced to `O(lg N)`

Comment: Please note (log(n))² ≠ 2log(n), and O((log n)²) ⊄ O(log(n))

Comment: @selbie , how do you find log2(n) for the second one?  

if you follow the formula of   log(upper-bound) - log (lower-bound) + 1   the j in the 2nd logarithm is an interruption 

besides multiplication of them can not be reduced so it's  pow (log , 2 )